# Register and use a logger with Unity in global.asax

Tags: asp.net, unity-container

I'm using Unity, and I register a logger like this:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    private ILogger _logger;

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ...
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<ILogger, NLogLogger>();

        container.RegisterControllers();

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));

        _logger = container.Resolve<ILogger>();
        _logger.Info("Application started");
    }
```

That seems to work fine - the message is logged.
Later in the global.asax.cs I have this:

```
    protected void Application_End()
    {
        _logger.Info("App is shutting down");
    }

    protected void Application_Error()
    {
        Exception lastException = Server.GetLastError();
        _logger.Fatal(lastException);
    }
```

However, this throws an exception -  _logger is null. I suspect I'm doing something wrong with Unity - so what's the correct way to use a logger inside global.asax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will actually want to re-resolve it from the DependencyResolver in each method where you use it. If you use an Application scoped `LifetimeManager` then you shouldn't be incurring any significant performance hit from the constructor. If you are not using an application scoped `LiftimeManager` then at least you won't be hit with a `NullReferenceException`!

```
protected void Application_End()
{
    var logger = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ILogger>();
    if(logger != null)
    {
        logger.Info("App is shutting down");
    }
}

protected void Application_Error()
{
    Exception lastException = Server.GetLastError();
    var logger = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ILogger>();
    if(logger != null)
    {
        logger.Fatal(lastException);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Another way is to make the logger static:

```
private static ILogger _logger;
```

Your logger implementation has to be thread safe, of course.